# C buffer overflow

Tags: c, string, char, buffer-overflow

I tried to make a function that replaces all occurrences of `str1` in a text `t` with `str2` but I keep getting a *"buffer overflow"* error message. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

//replace all *str1 in *t with *str2, put the result in *x, return *x
char * result(char *str1,char *str2,char *t)
{
    char *x=NULL,*p=t,*r=t;
    x=malloc(400*sizeof(char));
    assert(x!=NULL);
    x[0]='\0';
    r=strstr(t,str1); //r is at the first occurrence of str1 in t, p is at the beginning of t
    while(r!=NULL)
    {
        strncat(x,p,r-p); //copy r-p chars from p to x
        strcat(x,str2); //copy str2 to x
        p=r+strlen(str1); //p will be at the first char after the last occurrence of str1 in t
        r=strstr(r+strlen(str1),str1); //r goes to the next occurrence of str1 in t
    }
    strcat(x,p);
    return x;
}
```

I did not used the `gets()` function to read any `char` array.

My compiler is gcc version 4.6.3

---

I updated the code, it works, but the result is not the as expected.

`main()` function:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *sir="ab",*sir2="xyz",*text="cabwnab4jkab",*final;
    final=result(sir,sir2,text);
    puts(final);
    free(final);
    return 0;
}
```

printed string:

```
b
```

I expected `cxyzwnxyz4jkxyz`

Comment: You can't return `x`, it's local to the function.

Comment: see the edit re: your results and `strcat` vs. `strcpy`

Comment: Stepping through this code in a debugger or printing out the value of variables each time through the loop should make it fairly clear where the problem lies.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1 in C. While it's a minor style nit, it suggests deeper problems in your understanding of the language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you've got your [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) arguments mixed up: the second argument is the **source** string, not the limit on the number of chars to copy, which should be the third argument:

```
 strncpy(x, p, r - p); // copy r - p chars from p to x
```

Furthermore, you want to use `strcat` instead of `strcpy`. Using `strcpy`, you'll just overwrite the contents of the result with the replacement string, every time. Using `strcat`, be sure to initialize the result with `\0` before starting.

Finally, you're returning a reference to a local variable `x` from your function: you can't do this as the memory isn't usable after the function returns.

Comment: Thank you! I will try with dynamic allocation

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains quite a few weird bugs.

Firstly, `x` is a pointer to your destination buffer. For come reason you are doing all your copyings directly to `x`, i.e. everything is copied to the very beginning of the buffer, overwriting previously copied data. This doesn't make any sense at all. Whay are you doing this? You need to create a dedicated pointer to would keep the current destination position in `x` and write data to that position (instead of writing it to `x`).

I see that you edited your code and replaced copying with concatenation. Well... Even though it might fix the problem, this is still bad design. `strcat`/`strncat` functions have no place in good C code. Anyway, your code is still broken, since you are trying to use `strcat` functions on uninitialized buffer `x`. You need to initialize `x` as an empty string first.

Secondly, there's a more subtle problem with your search for replacement string. At the end of the cycle you continue the search from the next symbol `r=strstr(r+1,str1)`, i.e. you increment the search position by only 1. I'm not sure this is what you want.

Consider  `aaaa` as input text, and the request to replace `aa` with `bc`. How many replacements do you want to do in this case? How many occurrences of `aa` are there in `aaaa`? 2 or 3? If you want to get `bcbc` as the result (2 replacements), you have to increase `r` by `strlen(str1)`, not by 1.

In fact, in the current implementation you set `p=r+strlen(str1)`, but continue the search from `r+1` position. This will lead to completely meaningless results with overlapping occurrences of search string, as in my example. Try this

```
char *str1="aa",*str2="xyz",*text="aaaa",*final;
final=result(str1,str2,text);
```

and see what happens.